How to approximate a matrix with vector cross products with limited basis?
I have a real symmetric matrix
$$
M=
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
A & B & C \\ \hline
B^\top & D & E \\ \hline
C^\top & E^\top & F
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The basis is divided into three sets, noted as $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$. The matrix is thus divided into nine blocks. For example, the block $B$ is spanned by $\alpha$ in rows and $\beta$ in columns, and the block $E$ is spanned by $\beta$ in rows and $\gamma$ in columns.
Normally, we can diagonalize $M$ and express it by the sum of cross products of eigenvectors weighted by the eigenvalues.
$$
M=\sum_i n_i \mathbf{c}_i \mathbf{c}_i^\top
$$
where $\mathbf{c}_i$ is an eigenvector spanned by all the three basis sets and $n_i$ is the corresponding eigenvalue. For the specific problem I am dealing with, the eigenvalues are in $[0,1]$.
However, I am not satisfied with the "delocalized" expression of $M$. In other words, I don't want the eigenvectors to have all $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ components. Instead, I want each eigenvector to have only components from two sets, something like
$$
M\approx \sum_i^{N^{\alpha\beta}}n_i^{\alpha\beta}\mathbf{c}_i^{\alpha\beta} \mathbf{c}_i^{\alpha\beta\top} + \sum_i^{N^{\alpha\gamma}}n_i^{\alpha\gamma}\mathbf{c}_i^{\alpha\gamma} \mathbf{c}_i^{\alpha\gamma\top} + \sum_i^{N^{\beta\gamma}}n_i^{\beta\gamma}\mathbf{c}_i^{\beta\gamma} \mathbf{c}_i^{\beta\gamma\top}
$$
$\mathbf{c}_i^{\alpha\beta}$ is an "eigenvector" having nonzero elements only in the sets $\alpha$ and $\beta$. $N^{\alpha\beta}$, the number of the corresponding vectors, is set by the researcher based on some a priori knowledge. The "eigenvalues" $n_i^{\alpha\beta}$ is still in $[0,1]$. The "eigenvectors" are orthonormal.
Perhaps this can be considered an optimization problem. The approximate $M$ is optimized to resemble the true $M$ as much as possible. The question is that, there are too many embarrassing constraints:

$n_i^{\alpha\beta} \in [0,1]$;
The orthonormalization condition of $\mathbf{c}_i^{\alpha\beta}$;
$\mathbf{c}_i^{\alpha\beta}$ must have nonzero elements only in the sets $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
So the optimization is not trivial.

Does any existing technique help find a solution of these "eigenvalues" and "eigenvectors"?  I am totally blind in math field, so I want to benefit from some professional opinion. Many thanks!

Are two eigenvectors of different sets still needed to be orthogonal? Or does that only apply to eigenvectors of the same set?

Yes. Any pair of eigenvectors need to be orthogonal, regardless of the superscripts.

On second thought, perhaps eigenvectors of different superscripts can be not orthogonal, in my case. For example, c_1^\alpha\beta and c_2^\alpha\beta must be orthogonal, but c_1^\alpha\beta and c_1^\alpha\gamma can be not orthogonal.
